# Semantic word embedding for relationships?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word-embeddings

**Observation [1]**

*Word2vec* is pretty good at comparing "subjects", e.g.:

$$\langle dog, pup \rangle \simeq 0.81$$

$$\langle pants, trousers \rangle \simeq 0.75$$

But it appears to be not great at encoding "relationships" in a way that preserves semantics, e.g.:

$$\langle spouse, wife \rangle \simeq 0.52$$

$$\langle employer, boss \rangle \simeq 0.27$$

$$\langle own, posess \rangle \simeq 0.26
$$

**Questions**

1. Is there any obvious intuition for why this is the case?
2. Is there any well-known way to encoding these relationship-type words in a way that the cosine distance would actually successfully measure semantic similarity?

[1] I computed these examples with the [webapp here](http://bionlp-www.utu.fi/wv_demo/)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is there any obvious intuition for why this is the case?

Most likely these words appear in different contexts.

> 2. Is there any well-known way to encoding these relationship-type words in a way that the cosine distance would actually successfully measure semantic similarity?

You could try to operate on the embedding space, as in Piotr Migdał's [blog post](http://p.migdal.pl/2017/01/06/king-man-woman-queen-why.html) (*Differences and projections* part).

Other way to see what is in the blog post is that if you want embeddings of related words to be similar, you need to take a quotient of the word embedding space by the vector/subspace representing the relation (for example *king* - *queen* represents gender).

Comment: Would love to have some elaboration on the quotient thing.

Let $V$ be the total embedding space. I'm reading your example of quotient by the relation as something like this.

Let $G \equiv span(\{male, female\}) \subset V$, I consider the quotient defined by the exact sequence:

$$0 \to G \hookrightarrow V \xrightarrow{\pi} V/G \to 0$$

And the idea is that we'd have $\pi(king) = \pi(queen) \in V/G$.

**Question**: Is it actually true that the subspace $G$ contains only gender-related words? For example one might expect the word $eunuch$ to lay in that space.

Comment: The idea is to quotient by $span({male - female})$ or something like that. If you do this then $\pi(male) = \pi(female)$ and hopefully $\pi(king) \approx \pi(queen)$ etc

Comment: Interesting! Another way saying saying how you're representing relations is something like pick a basis for $V$, compute the standard codimension-1 simplex, then $0$-cells represent words and $1$-cells represent relationships.